# How to make VBA code faster/more efficient

Tags: excel, vba

So I have designed this code to insert new entries into my master Database Log but when I run the code it is much too slow.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long, i As Long, iRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Entry")
With ws
LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        If 2 > LR Then Exit Sub
        
        iRow = 3
                      
        For i = 1 To LR
        
        If .Cells(i, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 230, 251) Then
            
            Worksheets("Call Log").Rows("3:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            .Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 7).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Call Log").Cells(iRow, "A")
            
            
        End If
    Next i    
End With
Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

As you can see, my code goes through the range, determines if it matches my criteria (in this case the color of the cell) and then Inserts a row in the destination Worksheet and copies the data into that newly created row over and over until it finishes. I've thought of maybe having it select all of the necessary cells, copy and then insert them all at once into the destination worksheet, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: are the cells formatted due to conditional formatting?

Comment: They are not, at least not for the color it is searching for.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you are doing obsoletely, is copying something to the clipboard, while this is not necessary: instead of

```
Range("<somewhere>").Copy
Range("<elsewhere>").Paste
```

You might simply do:

```
Range("<elsewhere>".Value = Range("<somewhere>").Value
```

Comment: oh I hadn't thought of that, I did try it out in my code but what ended up happening is it was just inserting new rows but not copying the data. So I just ended up with a bunch of blank cells.

Comment: @KyoshiMartínez: I already wondered why you were copying without pasting, and now you know you don't need both of them :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to turn off screen updating and set calculations to manual (unless you need it)

```
Application.SceenUpdating = false
Application.calculations = xlmanual
```

Then set them back to true and xlautomatic at the end of the code.

Not sure if the syntaxes is correct, I'm typing from my phone

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to copy the source formatting of the cells also, then you could use a filter and then copy only the visible cells, all in one go. Something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Const shtDataName As String = "Data Entry"
    Const shtLogName As String = "Call Log"
    Dim shtData As Worksheet
    Dim shtLog As Worksheet
    '
    'Make sure required resources are available
    Set shtData = GetWorksheet(shtDataName, ThisWorkbook)
    If shtData Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Missing sheet <" & shtDataName & ">!", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set shtLog = GetWorksheet(shtLogName, ThisWorkbook)
    If shtLog Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Missing sheet <" & shtLogName & ">!", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '
    'Check last row
    Dim lastRow As Long
    '
    lastRow = shtData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub
    '
    Dim filterColor As Long
    '
    'Filter Range
    filterColor = RGB(217, 230, 251)
    With Range(shtData.Cells(1, 1), shtData.Cells(lastRow, 1))
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterColor, Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    End With
    '
    Dim rng As Range
    Const lastCol As Long = 7
    Dim firstRow As Long
    '
    'Get filtered range
    'First row remains visible regardless of filter. Check it
    If shtData.Cells(1, 1).Cells(1, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color <> filterColor Then
        firstRow = 2
    Else
        firstRow = 1
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Range(shtData.Cells(firstRow, 1), shtData.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'Nothing meets criteria
    '
    Dim tempArea As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    '
    'Get required rows count
    For Each tempArea In rng.Areas
        rCount = rCount + tempArea.Rows.Count
    Next tempArea
    '
    'Insert rows
    Const iRow As Long = 3
    '
    shtLog.Rows(iRow & ":" & iRow + rCount - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    rng.Copy shtLog.Cells(iRow, 1)
    '
    'Remove filter
    rng.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

But, if you don't care about source formatting then you could use something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Const shtDataName As String = "Data Entry"
    Const shtLogName As String = "Call Log"
    Dim shtData As Worksheet
    Dim shtLog As Worksheet
    '
    'Make sure required resources are available
    Set shtData = GetWorksheet(shtDataName, ThisWorkbook)
    If shtData Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Missing sheet <" & shtDataName & ">!", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set shtLog = GetWorksheet(shtLogName, ThisWorkbook)
    If shtLog Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Missing sheet <" & shtLogName & ">!", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '
    'Check last row
    Dim lastRow As Long
    '
    lastRow = shtData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub
    '
    'Read data in array (super fast)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim arrData() As Variant
    Const lastCol As Long = 7
    '
    Set rng = Range(shtData.Cells(1, 1), shtData.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    arrData = rng.Value2
    '
    'Store relevant row numbers
    Dim collRows As New Collection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim filterColor As Long: filterColor = RGB(217, 230, 251)
    '
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If rng.Cells(i, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = filterColor Then
            collRows.Add i
        End If
        '
        'I am not a fan of using colors for filtering. It's much faster to have a separate
        '   column (indicator column) that can be used for that. This way we could do
        '   something like: If arrData(i, indCol) = expectedValue Then ...
        ' which is much faster than accesing cells
    Next i
    '
    'Prepare data for writing
    Dim arrFiltered() As Variant
    ReDim arrFiltered(1 To collRows.Count, 1 To lastCol)
    Dim r As Variant
    Dim c As Long
    '
    i = 0
    For Each r In collRows
        i = i + 1
        For c = 1 To lastCol
            arrFiltered(i, c) = arrData(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    '
    'Insert rows
    Const iRow As Long = 3
    '
    shtLog.Rows(iRow & ":" & iRow + collRows.Count - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    '
    'Write
    With Range(shtLog.Cells(iRow, 1), shtLog.Cells(iRow + collRows.Count - 1, lastCol))
        .Value2 = arrFiltered
    End With
End Sub

Private Function GetWorksheet(ByVal sheetName As String, ByVal book As Workbook) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWorksheet = book.Worksheets(sheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

The above is rushed code but proves some ways of doing the task. Other things that need to be considered are:

1. Are the worksheets protected? if yes, filtering and inserting rows can be an issue
2. Inserting rows will fail if the rows are intersecting multiple dynamic tables (listobjects)
3. Code needs to be changed if data doesn't start on row 1 in the source

and probably others that don't come to mind right now